# Error calculating thevenin's equivalent

Tags: circuit-analysis

I tried this method but the answer is not matching. Where it all went wrong? [image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to solve the problem. And since Thevenin's Theorem states little more than:

> Any linear circuit containing several voltages and resistances can be
> replaced by just one single voltage in series with a single resistance
> connected across the load.

You are pretty much free to choose your approach in arriving at that destination.

### Norton-Thevenin transformation approach

You chose to use KVL. I prefer KCL. And I'll get to both.

But let's just take this simply, at first, and instead use a set of Norton-Thevenin transformations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPl59O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above should be obvious (and since you applied it yourself, I know you are aware of it.) On the left the only change I made is to set the \$B\$ node as my reference point, or ground. I then converted the Norton source of \$I_1\$ and \$R_1\$ into a Thevenin source shown on the right. And I simplified the schematic slightly, by dumping the entire voltage source and replacing it with a mere note about its voltage.

This is a really simple transformation from the above:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqrdju.png)</sup>

I shouldn't even need to explain that one, above. Easy.

At this point, all you have to do is the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgKG8s.png)</sup>

In going from the left side to the top right schematic above, you should already know how to transform a resistor divider that sits between any voltage pair. But just in case others may not be, I'll write it out: \$V_\text{equiv}=\frac{V_\text{A}\cdot R_\text{B}+V_\text{B}\cdot R_\text{A}}{R_\text{A}+R_\text{B}}\$ and \$R_\text{equiv}=\frac{R_\text{A}\cdot R_\text{B}}{R_\text{A}+R_\text{B}}\$, where \$V_\text{A}\$ and \$R_\text{A}\$ are the source voltage and source resistance from one side and \$V_\text{B}\$ and \$R_\text{B}\$ are the source voltage and source resistance from the opposite side of the divider. (It's worth working out by hand to see why these are correct.)

Well, that was easy.

### Nodal analysis

Another approach I like uses KCL instead of KVL. Here, referring back to the first schematic, we are looking first to find \$V_\text{A}\$ (which will be the same as \$V_\text{Y}\$ without a load), and find:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_2}&=3\:\text{A}+\frac{V_\text{Y}}{R_2}\\\\
\frac{V_\text{Y}}{R_2}+\frac{V_\text{Y}}{R_3}&=\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_2}+\frac{12\:\text{V}}{R_3}
\end{align*}$$

The above solves out as \$V_\text{Y}=19.2\:\text{V}\$. Just as we got, earlier.

To find the Thevenin resistance of the source, we simply inject \$1\:\text{A}\$ at node \$A\$ and find out the voltage:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_1}+\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_2}&=3\:\text{A}+\frac{V_\text{Y}}{R_2}\\\\
\frac{V_\text{Y}}{R_2}+\frac{V_\text{Y}}{R_3}&=\frac{V_\text{X}}{R_2}+\frac{12\:\text{V}}{R_3}+1\:\text{A}
\end{align*}$$

Here, we get \$V_\text{Y}=23.2\:\text{V}\$. And from this fact, we know that \$V_\text{A}=V_\text{Y}+1\:\text{A}\cdot R_4=24.2\:\text{V}\$. Therefore, the Thevenin resistance must be \$R_\text{TH}=\frac{24.2\:\text{V}-19.2\:\text{V}}{1\:\text{A}}=5\:\Omega\$.

Once again, same answer using a different approach.

### Your approach

Let's follow your KVL approach after your made that first Norton-Thevenin conversion:

$$0\:\text{V}+48\:\text{V}-I\cdot R_1 - I\cdot R_2 - I\cdot R_3= 12\:\text{V}$$

We find that \$I=1\frac{11}{25}\:\text{A}\$ and therefore \$V_\text{Y}=12\:\text{V}+I\cdot R_3=19.2\:\text{V}\$.

Same answer as before for the equivalent source voltage. Nothing new, here.

To get the equivalent source resistance, we can apply the given load resistance. Or, a more convenient one if we like: such as \$0\:\Omega\$. Let's do the latter (short \$A\$ to \$B\$.) We'll keep \$I\$ as the first loop's current (left side) but now we need another loop current, which I will call \$I_\text{X}\$ for the right side loop that goes through this new \$0\:\Omega\$ resistor at the output.

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V}+48\:\text{V}-I\cdot R_1 - I\cdot R_2 - \left(I-I_\text{X}\right)\cdot R_3&= 12\:\text{V}\\\\
0\:\text{V}+12\:\text{V}-\left(I_\text{X}-I\right)\cdot R_3-I_\text{X}\cdot R_4&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

We don't really care about \$I\$ but the above solves out as \$I_\text{X}=3.84\:\text{A}\$. So \$V_\text{A}\$ went from \$19.2\:\text{V}\$ to \$0\:\text{V}\$ while the current from \$A\$ to \$B\$ went from \$0\:\text{A}\$ to \$3.84\:\text{A}\$. From this, we find the equivalent source resistance from the perspective of \$A\$ as being \$\frac{19.2\:\text{V}}{3.84\:\text{A}}=5\:\Omega\$.

Again, same results from varying methods.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Where is \$V_{O}\$ measured across? Draw that in your second schematic (after the source transform) and your mistake should become clear.

Comment: Vo is across the load.. The 10ohm resistor

Comment: Yes, I see that. Indicate what that looks like in your schematic. Then it should be very obvious that the statement \$V_{TH} = 5\times i\$ is incorrect.